# how to run jdbc sink connector on windows command prompt? alternative of curl command in windows cmd

Tags: cmd, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In linux we can run this code using  curl command but i need command for windows platform

```
POST /connectors HTTPS
Host:
Authorization: Basic Auth (Provide the credentials used when creating the cluster)
Content-Type: application/json
{
"name": "myconnectorname",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "mytopic",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://<mymysqlurl>:<portnumber>/schemaname",
    "connection.user": "myusername",
    "connection.password": "mypassword",
    "connection.password.secure.key": "mycredentialstorekey",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://curl.haxx.se/windows/

Answer (score 1):

You can use any REST client, like PostMan or Insomnia.

Powershell also has a HTTP client, similar to cURL or you can use [cURL in Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/windows/), or use WSL.

There are also Kafka Connect user-interface projects on Github